# SCALA REPL throwing error at launch

Tags: scala

I get the following error when I try to run the SCALA REPL. Note that I have already looked into this post where it talks about downgrading java version.

```
sg@IN0D196716 C:\Users\sg
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

sg@IN0D196716 C:\Users\sg
$ scala
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.util.matching.Regex.unapplySeq(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Lscala/Option;
        at scala.tools.nsc.settings.ScalaVersion$.apply(ScalaVersion.scala:104)
        at scala.tools.nsc.settings.ScalaVersion$.apply(ScalaVersion.scala:114)
        at scala.tools.nsc.settings.ScalaVersion$.<init>(ScalaVersion.scala:119)
        at scala.tools.nsc.settings.ScalaVersion$.<clinit>(ScalaVersion.scala)
        at scala.tools.nsc.settings.ScalaSettings$class.$init$(ScalaSettings.scala:138)
        at scala.tools.nsc.settings.MutableSettings.<init>(MutableSettings.scala:20)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Settings.<init>(Settings.scala:12)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerSettings.<init>(GenericRunnerSettings.scala:11)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:18)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:41)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: what scala version do you have?

Comment: 2.11.7 is what I have. However if I do "sbt console" I can get to the scala REPL from there

Comment: Maybe something similar to this? http://qnalist.com/questions/5449144/problem-bug-with-scala-2-11-0-m3-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, dude, that's my fault.

A few years ago, someone said you should only be able to use a regex to extract from strings (char sequences).

That was such a reasonable request. "Tell me if I try to match a regex to something that isn't even a string!"

Unfortunately, because JVM and maven and ivy, you never know what backwards compatibility issues you'll discover.

As you have discovered.

Scala requires that you build and run with the same "major" version.

Here is a similar issue where "user experience" diverges:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9380

Additional apologies if you don't prefer the gendered "dude", if it is gendered.

Comment: haha I dont mind you calling me dude. My question is I am not even trying to compile anything, just trying to launch the interpreter though.

Comment: You've got a classpath problem. `scala-compiler.jar` and `scala-libary.jar` are picked up from different versions. You can try `scala -Ylog-classpath` which may tell you the difference.